# Possible to specify "content type" in Facebook Graph API requests

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've joined a NodeJS project where one of the tasks is to fetch data from Facebook via the Graph API. The request URL is of this format:

```
"https://${host}/${apiVersion}/me/${contentTypePluralLowercaseName}?access_token=${accessToken}"
```

where the app fills in the host, in this case I believe it's "api.facebook.com", fills in a string based on the current content type ("Post", "Friend", etc), and adds the access token.

I'm a bit confused about the role of "content type" in forming the final URL though -- I have searched the FB Graph API docs and don't see any reference to it.  Instead, it seems you limit the search type by adding `?fields=` and then specifying what you want.  I don't see any other way in which you can request content type.

I'm having to parse someone else's code and am a bit confused -- any insight welcome!

Comment: At this position in the URL, it refers to what is called an "edge" in Graph API terminology, so stuff like `feed`, `posts`, `videos`, etc. Go check the docs for the user and page objects, they are listed in there.

Comment: Thanks -- indeed, this is it.  If I may ask -- what is the difference, in this case, between specifying an edge, e.g. "photos", and adding a field of "photos"?  Does it have the same effect -- I'm reading through the docs, and perhaps it's obvious there, but the API reference seems to deal with each individual case (edge or field), not what the differences between them are.

Comment: There is no difference when it comes to the `fields` parameter, that is used for fields and edges. Basically you can say a field is a property of an object (user name, user email, etc.), whereas edges are connections, lists of other objects that have some relation with the current object (user/friends will return a list of users, page/feed a list of posts, post/sharedposts a list of posts that shared this one, …)

Comment: Thanks, yes -- my confusion was because the first edge I was asked to deal with was "photos" (I think, from memory, it's users/photos) and I was also add the field "photos" -- in this case it seemed there was some overlap, that is, in forming a URL (this is an approximation) like https://${host}/${apiVersion}/me/photos?access_token=${accessToken}?fields=photos there would be a duplication.  I understand what you're saying though…